# PHP - MYSQL Search Engine - Matching specific letters from a word in a search box

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to make search engine to match some specific letters from the end of the word I input in a search box, or the first few letters in the the beginning of a word, that I input in the search box.

So, I have a search engine, a MySql database containing a simple table ID and WORDS. When I hit search button, I want the result to display me the words in WORDS column, matching the end of the word I am searching. I want to be able to choose how many letters to match my search from some radio buttons or drop-down (1, 2, 3, 4) last letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a database query using [MySQL's 'LIKE' operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
SELECT words FROM your_table WHERE word LIKE 'foo%'
```

for words beginning with 'foo' or

```
SELECT words FROM your_table WHERE word LIKE '%foo'
```

for ending with 'foo'. The % is a wildcard, matching any other characters in the word.

Use PHP's s[ubstr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to make the string the right length and then add the % at the beginning or end depending on whether you want words ending or beginning with the characters.

Comment: Hi, Your answers seem OK to me and in a logical way, but how can I implement it in my code having $result=$db->query("SELECT words FROM table WHERE words LIKE '%$searchterm%' "); ... because I already have a like. How can I pun this "foo" into code... a checkbox or something? Do I need to spleet the searchterm with something like $string = str_split($string);? and how do I select last chars? Thanks!

Comment: Note that using LIKE with a wildcard at the start of the string is slow with lots of rows, since it does a full table scan.